# foreach inside while loop not work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to display a list of cars with specifications: weight, length, width.
Everything would be inside a foreach and inside a while, but I cant run it properly...

My tables
cars:
idcar: 1 / width:30 / length:10 / weight:300
idcar: 2 / width:20 / length:12 / weight:210
idcar: 3 / width:20 / length:21 / weight:230
idcar: 4 / width:40 / length:11 / weight:210

and specs table:
idspec:1 spec:width
idspec:2 spec:weight
idspec:3 spec:length
And my code

```
$idcar = $_GET['idcar'];
$resultcarfirst = mysqli_query($connecDB,"select * from products order by (case idcar when $idcar then 0 else idcar end), $idcar asc");
$resultspec = mysqli_query($connecDB, "SELECT * FROM specs ORDER BY idspec");

while($rowspec = mysqli_fetch_array($resultspec)){
        echo '<div><h1>'.$rowspec["spec"].'</h1><br/>';

        $arraycars = array();
        while($rowcar = mysqli_fetch_array($resultcarfirst))
        $arraycars[] = $rowcar;
        foreach($arraycars as $rowcar){
            echo '<p>idcar:'.$rowcar['idcar'].' '.$rowspec['spec'].': '.$rowcar[$rowspec['spec']].'</p>';
        }

        echo '</div><br/>';
    }
```

The output would be:
Width
idcar:1 width:30
idcar:2 width:20
idcar:3 width:20
idcar:4 width:40

Weight
idcar:1 weight:300
idcar:2 weight:210
idcar:3 weight:230
idcar:4 weight:210

Length
idcar:1 length:10
idcar:2 length:12
idcar:3 length:21
idcar:4 length:11

Thank you and i hope I was clear.

Comment: You mention what output you desire, but what do you actually get as output?

Comment: your code is missing a couple of braces for it to do what you want to do, I think.

Comment: @fvy im sorry, In my output I cant show all the spec with each of the cars. Only the first spec with cars, then all empty. Am I clear? thank you.

Comment: @Aralicia, Im not very good with php, but if youre talking about the second while, I found it in another post and it works ok. I think. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

WHy would you do this..??

All you need is...

```
    $arraycars = array();
    while($rowcar = mysql_fetch_array($resultcarfirst)){
    echo '<p>idcar:'.$rowcar['idcar'].' '.$rowspec['name'].':    '.$rowcar[$rowspec['spec']].'</p>';
    $arraycars[] = $rowcar;}
```

Unless Im completely misunderstanding what you want to do.?

Also...if you wanna pull the sspecs only for that car....with that while loop, then you have to change your query to accept a variable from the first while loop, if you know what I mean

Comment: Im sorry, Im not understanding

Comment: I need to repeat, in the first instance, many spec in my db. Second step show all cars in each of the spec, depending on this. ie:If it is wide: all cars with width value, if it's high: all cars with high value.

Comment: Then you'll need to either do a join in mysql, or as you loop send the query.....either way

Comment: Youre going about this all wrong....look up table joins, without seeing the structure of your two tables, I cant help you further